# Plotly fx.hover fails for mobile

Tags: reactjs, plotly

I keep receiving this warning when trying to click anywhere on my graph with Chrome's mobile helper turned on. Couldn't find much on Plotly's documentation for their hover events, and the I couldn't get much from the stack trace either. Any suggestions? I'm trying to be able to click on a certain data point and view its data just like you can when hovering on desktop (screenshots attached).

[image: plotly's warning in console after trying to tap on screen]
[image: desktop shows data point on hover]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in Plotly, the latest version that worked for me was 1.28.0. You can retrieve a specific version from the CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.28.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out later and get back to you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I'm even having problems on Plotly's own website, so I decided to just create an issue on github